# Retrieving MySQL records based on a variable set of points of comparison

Tags: php, mysql, comparison, combinations

Let's say I have a MySQL table, `people`. Each record comprises a variety of properties, among these `favourite_colour`, `country`, and `age_group`.

What I would like to do is retrieve records from this table by their similarity to a set of specific parameters. Given "Red", "United States", and "18-25", for example, the best results would be those records that match all three. These would be 100% matches.

However, I would also like to retrieve records that match any combination of two parameters (66% match), or any one parameter (33% match). Moreover, I would like to be able to define additional points of comparison (e.g. `underwear_type`, `marital_status`, etc.).

Is there a relatively efficient solution to this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can turn each comparison, such as `favourite_colour='Red'` &c, into a value of 0 (false) or 1 (true) -- mysql will do it implicitly, but for generality you might want
`CAST( (favourite_colour='Red') AS INTEGER)` &c; then, you `SUM` all of these, i.e.,

```
SELECT
userId,
SUM( (favourite_colour='Red'),
     (country='US'),
     (age_group='18-25') ) AS match_score
FROM people
WHERE match_score >= 2
ORDER BY match_score DESC
```

will give you perfect matches first, 2-of-3 next; easy to generalize to even more checks!-)

Comment: This is indeed a very good idea. It would be easy to add weighing to this too by multiplying one of the results.

Comment: This is indeed a great solution. A couple notes/questions: from what I can tell, SQL doesn't allow column aliases (ie. match_score) in WHERE clauses. Also, I don't think SUM() behaves as your query would suggest (it doesn't accept multiple arguments); MySQL's documentation indicates SUM() is a GROUP BY aggregation function only. Removing the WHERE clause, and replacing sum with addition operators made the function work like a charm.

Comment: @Hoobnium, good points -- I was apparently making up my own too-sensible SQL dialect, on both the SUM and WHERE issues;-). Thanks for double checking!

Answer (score 0):

For the three first is easy:

```
select * from people
where
(case when color = 'Red' then 33 else 0 end + 
case when age_group = '18-25' then 33 else 0 end + 
case when country = 'United States' then 33 else 0 end)>=33
```

I don't understand the "additional points of comparison" part, can you explain?

Comment: This is not very usable or elegant.

Comment: Compared with Alex's solution, I must agree!. But it works anyway.

Comment: That's why StackOverflow is here :) to find the best solution.

Comment: @tekBlues: By additional points of comparison, I meant that I might, at a future date, add another fields (like `underwear_type`) to compare against. Matches would then be 25%/50%/75%/100%.